# How to cv2.imread an image within a zipfile?

Tags: python, opencv, python-zipfile

I'm trying to use OpenCV2 to read images withing a zipfile with `cv2.imread` and then resize them and save them but I can't figure out how to read those images within the zipfile. This is my code so far:

```
import cv2
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("sample_images.zip", "r") as zipFile:
    imgs = zipFile.namelist()
    img = zipFile.open(imgs[0])
    processedImg = cv2.imread(img)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yash/Desktop/Programming/opencv test/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    processedImg = cv2.imread(img)
SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Comment: `img = zipFile.open(imgs[0])` gives a zipfile object of the image but `cv2.imread()` expects a string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PIL import Image

with ZipFile("sample_images.zip", "r") as zipFile:
    imgs = zipFile.namelist()
    print(imgs[0])
    img = zipFile.read(imgs[0])
    processedImg = Image.open(BytesIO(img))
    processedImg.show()
```